# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' error

Tags: python, flask

Flaskでアプリケーションを作っています。

```
@app.route('/my-route')
def my_route():
  id = request.args.get('id')
  schema = Schema({
    Required('id'): All(Coerce(str))
})
try:
    schema({'id': id})
except MultipleInvalid as e:
    str(e)

  ans=test(session[‘id’])
  return ans
```

とコードを書きました。アプリを実行して、localhost:8000/my-route?id=aDj1948　にアクセスすると、
builtins.TypeError TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' のエラーが起こりました。
なぜこのようなエラーが出るのでしょうか？僕は > 記号を使っていなく、なぜこのようなエラーが起こるのか理解できません。どのように直せば良いでしょうか？

Comment: `validators.py", line 535` をみるかぎり、 `voluptuous`の`Range`部分でエラーが発生しているようです。実行中アプリケーションのソースの`Schema`定義内に`Range`のルールが残っていないでしょうか?

Comment: 今回の質問について解決したのであれば一旦終了して、新な問題を切り分けて不明点を別途質問されると良いと思います。